# copy Column B of sheet2 by matching values of Column A from sheet2 to Column A sheet1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a complex scenario, I want to copy Column B of sheet2  to Column C of sheet1 by match cells of column A of sheet2 against Column A sheet1, please have a look at below tables.

**Sheet 1**

[image]

**Sheet 2**

[image]

**Resultant Sheet 1 After formula**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its no so complex. Try `Index/Match` like-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"")
```

`VLookup()` will also work in this way-

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

With `Excel365`, single `XLOOKUP()` will give you desired result.

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , This works. this did the track.
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"")